# jquery hasclass or toggleclass issue

Tags: jquery

i have a form with `.myclass`, inside some `ul` -> `li` -> `label`

when I use `addClass` this works:

```
$(".myclass label").each(function (){
    var $this = $(this);        
    $this.on("click", function(){
        $this.addClass("active");
    });
});`
```

but when I try to check if the class exists nothing happens

```
$(".myclass label").each(function (){
    var $this = $(this);    
    $this.on("click", function(){
        if($this.hasClass("active"))
            $this.removeClass("active");
        else
            $this.addClass("active");
    });
});
```

I tried to use `toggleClass` but nothing.
Where i'm wrong?

*edit sorry, I forgot that there is an `<input>` inside the label:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="myClass">
 <ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
    <li class="item-1"><label><input type="checkbox">my label 1</label></li>
    <li class="item-22"><label><input type="checkbox">my label 2</label></li>
    <li class="item-34"><label><input type="checkbox">my label 3</label></li>
```

etc...

Comment: Works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/t233kL5a/

Comment: Yep, works fine as adeneo says. Note that you could improve the logic by removing the `each` and using `toggleClass`. Have you checked the console for errors elsewhere in your code?

Comment: what you actually want?

Comment: Can we see the DOM?  I wonder if your selector and DOM is such that you're firing the click event twice and immediately turning the active flag on and then off.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.myclass label').on('click', function (event) {
    if( $(event.target).is("label") ) {
        if ($(event.target).hasClass("active"))  {   
            $(event.target).removeClass("active");
        }else{
            $(event.target).addClass("active");
        }
    }
});
```

the problem was twice click generated by label->input.